# Injecting a spring bean to a module in AXIS2

Tags: web-services, spring, module, apache-axis, handlers

I am using axis2 framework for my webservices. I am created a module. Now How can i inject my spring beans to a module . What i means is for examples for services below is the what we generally do.

```
<service name="TestWebService" scope="application">
<description>
    TestWebService
       </description>

<schema schemaNamespace="http://axis.apache.org/axis2" />

<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
        class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
        class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
</messageReceivers>

      <parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier">org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringServletContextObjectSupplier
</parameter>
<parameter name="SpringBeanName">SampleWebService</parameter>


<module ref="soapValidation" />
<module ref="rampart" />
   </service>
```

In the same way for below module.xml how can i inject a spring bean

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <module name="soapValidation"
                class="com.test.axis.handlers.AddOperationSchemaValidatorModule">
            <InFlow>
                <handler name="InFlowSoapValidationHandler"
                                                                                                            class="com.test.axis.handlers.AddOperationSchemaValidatorHandler">
        <order phase="soapRequestValidationPhase" />
                    </handler>
        </InFlow>
            </module>
```

Thanks,
Naredra

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?